# Is there a way to stop DVD player and other apps from defaulting to full screen?

Tags: fullscreen

Whenever DVD Player launches (iMac running Mojave), it goes full screen, with no way to stop it. This also happens when entering a meeting with either Zoom, or GoToMeeting, or both.

I have precisely zero interest in running *anything* full-screen on this Mac; if I want to run something full screen, I'll use one of my PC-DOS 2000 boxes.

Comment: Cmd/Ctrl/F toggles fullscreen in many apps. Once you take anything out of fullscreen it should launch that way next time. Nothing should ever default to fullscreen. [I truly loathe fullscreen for anything other than watching a movie, so I'm with you on this one]

Comment: Yeah, that should be the case.

Comment: No joy in DVD player. Cmd/Ctrl/F exits fullscreen, but as soon as I close the window, the program exits, and if I eject and reinsert the DVD, it once again immediately launches DVD player, and immediately goes to full screen.

Comment: Test on a different account.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, DVD Player defaults to opening full screen. You can hit Esc to switch to windowed mode.
Also being a "single-window" app, it will quit if the only window is closed.